# Lightweight jquery combobox to drop jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm using jQuery + jQuery UI for a very simple page.

I rely at the moment on jQuery UI autocomplete but:

- no need to autocomplete, only numbers are required, if dropdown is opened all values must be shown
- jQuery UI icons and font size — default in demos is 62.5% — does not fit the design I want: bigger text, bigger icons.

So I'd like to find a recent jQuery combobox plugin that:

1. let the user type in his own values without queriyng the server (way faster)
2. ajax loads available values and let user choose
3. NICE TO HAVE: keyboard support...

I can only find huge plugins *OR* old plugins...